# Background-Fetch: Cannot read property 'configure' of Undefined

Tags: react-native, background-fetch

I have been trying to integrate the transistorsoft background-fetch library without success:
https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-fetch

When I chain any method to the BackgroundFetch component I get the error (attached in this post)

[image]

```
import BackgroundFetch from "react-native-background-fetch";

class TimerScreen extends React.Component {

...

componentDidMount() {

    this.configureBackgroundFetch();

}
...
configureBackgroundFetch() {
    // Configure BackgroundFetch.
    BackgroundFetch.configure({
      minimumFetchInterval: 15, // <-- minutes (15 is minimum allowed)
      stopOnTerminate: false, // <-- Android-only,
      startOnBoot: true, // <-- Android-only
      enableHeadless: true
    }, async () => {
      console.log('BackgroundFetch has started');
      BackgroundFetch.finish(BackgroundFetch.FETCH_RESULT_NEW_DATA);
    }, (error) => {
      console.log('RNBackgroundFetch failed to start')
    });
}
...
```

I haven't been able to find out why the library isn't working. I have used react native link and installed it in package.json

```
 ...
 {
       ...
       "react-native-background-fetch": "^2.5.3",
       ...
 }
 ...
```

Comment: Did you try react-native link?

Comment: Yes I have used react-native link. It says react-native-background-fetch is already linked. It is an ejected app from Expo, does that cause any issues?

Comment: import { BackgroundFetch } from "react-native-background-fetch"; can you try this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by Expokit not being configured correctly to use native modules. I made a bare React Native app and the library worked without returning an error.